# No records are added to DataTable in Linq Select from DbCommand.ExecuteReader

Tags: linq, datareader

This code looks like it should work, in fact it compiles and runs. However, the records from the `cmd.ExecuetReader()` (and there are records,) are not being added to `dt` as expected. Anyone see what could be missing?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteReader().Cast<DbDataRecord>().Cast<DataRow>().Select(r=>dt.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray));
```

Or, is there a more straightforward way of doing this, using linq of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Linq is lazy. It just get executes when you actually access it's data.

This might work:

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
var data = cmd.ExecuteReader().Cast<DbDataRecord>().Cast<DataRow>().Select(r=>r.ItemArray).ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach(var d in data)
    dt.Rows.Add(d);
```

Calling `ToList()` forces linq to execute

Comment: Thanks. Actually just found out that this casting: Cast<DbDataRecord>().Cast<DataRow>() throws an exception at runtime. So it's not going to work. Need another method. But I'd hate to do the silly iteration of the reader when linq should be able to do this.

Comment: Here's the answer, non-linq answer.

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(x, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);

Comment: Good. I was looking into a way to add a collection of rows to the DataTable, as I'm not very friendly with them. They usually lead to bad OO design.